# TagLib crashes when destructing TagLib::File and couldn't close opened TagLib::File

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, crash, taglib

I am trying to make a music player using TagLib library (1.11.1) in Qt5 C++. I opened multiple files and read tags. And I encountered with two difficulties. After opening a file and reading the tags I couldn't close the file and deallocate memory occupied by the file. I used `delete` to free up memory and close the file. But when I try this the program crashes. Here is snip code of my program:

```
QString audioPath("song.mp3")
auto file = new MPEG::File(audioPath.toStdWString().c_str());

if (file->isOpen()) {
    auto tag = file->ID3v2Tag();
    if (tag) {
        //read audio tags
    }
}

delete file;
```

- When I remove `delete file;` it works perfect but there is memory leakage special when opening multiple files.
- If I opened a file I couldn't open it again because there is no way to close the opened file without exiting the program. And leaves me with this error:

> TagLib: Could not open file song.mp3

Is there a way to solve the memory leak and close the opened file?

And when I run debugging with `delete file;` I see this message:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.
>   Signal name:      SIGSEGV
>   Signal meaning:   Segmentation fault

[Program crashing message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5xJk.png)

Comment: Can you give us debugger output after the crash ? (stack overflow? bad access, heap coruption crash ?)

Comment: Sorry @Raxvan ... It is my first time to post a question. I have added the debugging result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need delete `file` by yourself. Instead of this use [FileRef](http://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1FileRef.html#a7428f0eb392142ca26e175f77270ca1f) class.
It will take care about deleting `file` object.
Example:

```
TagLib::String str(audioPath.toUtf8().constData(), TagLib::String::UTF8 );
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
TagLib::FileName fname(str.toCWString());
#else
TagLib::FileName fname(str.toCString(true));
#endif
TagLib::FileRef ref(fname, true, TagLib::AudioProperties::Accurate);
if(!ref.isNull()) {
    auto mpeg = dynamic_cast<TagLib::MPEG::File*>(ref.file());

    if(mpeg) {
        TagLib::ID3v2::Tag* tag = mpeg->ID3v2Tag();
        if(tag) {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny, It solved all my problems. I discover in my code i have deleted manually some of the tags and that led to crashing of the program.